# Register all system-fonts kivy

Tags: python-3.x, fonts, kivy, label

So simce kivy has only 2 or 3 fonts by default I want to add all system fonts to it.
Do i have to parse all fonts in C://windows/fonts manually via LabelBase.register or is there any function for that?

Comment: Kivy's font specifiers probably always expect a filename, but there's probably some way to add directories to the list of paths that will be searched by the resource finder.

Comment: I have used system fonts just by specifying the name of the font file as `font_name`, without concerning myself about the folder. At least for me (and I don't think I have done anything special), it just works.

Comment: Yeah normal fonts work with the filename (after adding base directory) though bold and italic do not work if you use non registered fonts. Guess i have to add them by hand :(